# How to get transaction history for yum?

Tags: linux, yum, package-management, packages

I would like to know how to get the transaction history of `yum` (i.e. get the installations, deletions, etc.), hopefully ordered from most to least recent.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
yum history
```

You can get the details of a specific transaction with:

```
yum history info 92
```

To revert a transaction:

```
yum history undo 92
```

See also the `yum` man page for more options you can use.